# Force AD Security Group Changes to Appear in Exchange

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, groups

I made changed to security groups within AD, and when I go to the GAL in Outlook I noticed that the changes were not reflected, even after forcing an update by clicking Send Receive | Send Receive Groups | Download Address Book.

So I checked the Exchange Management Console and noticed that the changes are not reflected there even after forcing a refresh.  Do I need to force an update push from AD somehow?  If so, how  do I accomplish this?

****UPDATE****

I don't know if there are two sets of groups that are named the same for convention or what.  I am thinking I might have changed the wrong one Sorry if I am not explicit but this is not my expertise.  The group I had changed was within ADUaC under

**.com\CustomOU\Groups\Distribution Groups\Security Groups*

The group members match the group I am attempting to rename in the GAL for Exchange.   In Exchange these groups are found under

*Microsoft Exchange On-Premises\Recipient Configuration\Distribution Group*.  Display name to rename (dgA) within this container is in OU

**.com\Users*

But the group (dgA) isn't found direcly within **.com\Users* so i did a Find within the domain and only found the one within **.com\CustomOU\Groups\Distribution Groups\Security Groups* which is what I changed.

If there is a concept I am missing here please let me know.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the type of change you made? I'm assuming you're referring to mail-enabled security groups?

Comment: And these security groups are mail-enabled?

Comment: I provided additional information by editing the original post.